# Cowboy rest handler and gen_servers communication

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I have cowboy rest handler which should spawn couple gen_servers.
What is the best way to send/handle messages in my cowboy handler?
Is there only one possibility to send message from gen_server to handler using "!" operator?

Answer (score 4):

Cowboy spawns an Erlang process with each request. You could use standard message passing but I don't think it would lead to an elegant solution.

Why not use `gen_server:call` and `gen_server:cast` to send a message from the cowboy handler? Even better when you wrap `call` and `cast` in a proper API.

Comment: Yes, I use cast/call when message goes from cowboy to custom gen_server, but then gen_server should send an answer and it seems it's only possible with "!" operator.

Comment: `cast` will always return `ok`. It's intended for asynchronous processing. For `call`s you can reply with `{reply, my_response_message, State}.` at the end of a `handle_call`. The caller will receive `my_response_message`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use Cowboy's [loop handler](https://github.com/extend/cowboy/blob/master/guide/loop_handlers.md) concept. Make your handler a loop handler and then send messages to it from your gen_servers using `!`

Comment: is possible to mix loop handler and rest handler?

Comment: No, that's not possible, REST handler in cowboy designed around concept of "operation on resource", so it is not the good place to do some hard stuff. Anyway, you could handcraft your own loop handler for your problem. But for me, it seems that existing REST handler, which basically spawn new `gen_server`s and do `call` inside them, should suffice.

Comment: yes, it's pity that erlang world is not fully implemented as Java and many actions should be reimplemented by each developer again and again :(